# Powershell get infos about files and try to Export them

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, export

I try do write a script where i can choose a folder and powershell shows me the Name, Size,.... of all the files in that folder. After that powershell should export the Informations in a Excel Table. 
But im stuck and dont know what to do :C

Here is my code that i tried to build

```
Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory)

{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")|Out-Null

    $foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $foldername.Description = "Select a folder"
    $foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"

    if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
    {
        $folder += $foldername.SelectedPath
    }
    return $folder
}

$a = Get-Folder

$folder = $a
Get-ChildItem -Path $folder | SELECT Name, @{Name="Size In KB";Expression={$_.Length / 1Kb}}, Attributes, LastaccessTime, @{n='Owner';e={(get-acl $_.Fullname).Owner}}| Format-Table -AutoSize 

Export-Csv "C:\Users\DZimmermann\Desktop\Test.csv" -Delimiter ";" -Append
```

Comment: Remove `Format-Table -AutoSize` because that only sends output to the console window. Leaqve the pipe symbol, so the output will go to `Export-Csv`.

Comment: i does it but it just happens nothing...

Comment: If you left the pipe symbol after the `SELECT` line, you should have a CSV file with all info you wanted. Nothing shows in the console because everything goes to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, using `Format-Table -AutoSize` simply outputs the info in a table format to console. It returns nothing, so there is nothing to write in the csv file..

Doing like this will create the CSV file and writes the info in there:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $folder | 
    Select-Object Name, 
                  @{Name="Size In KB";Expression={$_.Length / 1Kb}}, 
                  Attributes, LastaccessTime, 
                  @{n='Owner';e={(get-acl $_.Fullname).Owner}} |
    Export-Csv "C:\Users\DZimmermann\Desktop\Test.csv" -Delimiter ";"
```

This will not get you the info on screen. If you also want that, capture the result in a variable first:

```
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder | 
    Select-Object Name, 
                  @{Name="Size In KB";Expression={$_.Length / 1Kb}}, 
                  Attributes, LastaccessTime, 
                  @{n='Owner';e={(get-acl $_.Fullname).Owner}} 

#output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# write the CSV file:                  
$result | Export-Csv "C:\Users\DZimmermann\Desktop\Test.csv" -Delimiter ";"
```

P.S. judging by the title of this question, I think you only want info about Files, not Directories..
If that is the case, add `-File` switch to the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet (for PS 3 and up). For PS versions below 3 use

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $folder | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }
```

Comment: Thank you so much thats exactly what i was looking for <3